# ScrollView with SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, eclipse, scrollview, android-relativelayout, slidingdrawer

I am working with slidingdrawer for the first time and i don't know why I can't click on my drawer button. I think that is becouse I can't use it in ScrollView, is true? this is my code:

`

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:handle="@+id/drawerHandle" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/drawerHandle">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/help_tab_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="300dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/laycarbonara"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carbonara1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/carbonara1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvcarbonara1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/tvcarbonara1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carbonara2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/carbonara2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvcarbonara2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/tvcarbonara2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carbonara3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/carbonara3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvcarbonara3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/tvcarbonara3"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carbonara4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/carbonara4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvcarbonara4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/tvcarbonara4"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

If I use LinearLayout, SlidingDrawer function normally, for this I think that the problem is ScrollView

Answer (score -1):

try this:

first put ScrollView

then put SlidingDrawer

or set ScrollView transparent color like #90AABBCC